# magento upgrade fails

Tags: magento

I'm having major problems upgrading magento 1.4.2 to 1.6. Nothing that I found so far online was successful. Uploading 20 000 files via FTP fails, using mage fails. Recently I followed this tutorial:

```
chmod 700 ./pear

./pear mage-setup .
./pear install --force magento-core/Mage_Downloader
./pear install --force magento-core/Mage_All_Latest

chmod 700 ./mage

./mage sync-pear
./mage install http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community Mage_All_Latest --force

chmod 700 ./mage

./mage config-set preferred_state stable
```

When it finishes and I try to load the website I get "Welcome to Magento's Installation Wizard!", so I assume upgrading failed and that's the same as to install magento from scratch.

I got it on dedicated server running CentOS 5.3, PHP 5.3.6, MySQL Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.58 and Plesk 10.

Answer (score 1):

Normally I just upload the new base Magento files and visit the shop in a web browser. That should automatically initiate the upgrade.

If transferring 20,000 files is a problem, use a checksum tool and only transfer newer files. That should work.